# How to handle return traffic from backend servers using nginx as UDP loadbalancer

Tags: nginx, udp

I am having Nginx server set up as a UDP load balancer. I have a couple of backend servers that are handling the UDP traffic and for each packet the backend server receives, it replies with ACK. I am able to test it and get the response back when sending the request to the backend server directly, but when sending the packet over the nginx load balancer I am not receiving the traffic.

However, what I see, the response is sent back using higher, ephemeral ports.

Is this even possible with Nginx? I am using standard community version, but in case that Plus version supports this behavior, that is also an option. How can I achieve this?

The configuration is pretty straightforward as shown below. The UDP traffic is being load balanced.

```
stream {
  upstream udp {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:nnnnn;
     server xx.xx.xx.xx:nnnnn;
  }

  server {
    listen nnnnn udp;
    proxy_pass udp;
    proxy_responses 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

UDP connections from clients often use **well defined destination port numbers on the server** while client's side port numbers are usually ephemeral and that's perfectly fine.

It is the sender/initiating side who specifies **destination port on the destination machine**.

If the destination is a server (originator is a client), then source port is very likely to be ephemeral port, and destination port is very likely to be well-known port (1-1024) and vice versa.

Anyway this should work for you (note the `proxy_bind` property)

```
stream {
  server {
    listen nnnn udp;
    proxy_pass udp_servers;
    proxy_responses: 0;
    proxy_bind <IP_ADDRESS_OUTSIDE>;
  }

  upstream udp_servers {
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:nnnnn;
    server yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:mmmmm;
  }

}
```